# Wordpress - Setting custom template for multiple custom post types

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I was wondering if anyone knew how to set up a single template for multiple custom post types. For example - I don't want to set up multiple templates that do the exact same thing.

### Code

I found the following snippet while searching and it doesn't seem to work. I have placed this in `functions.php` in the theme I am using.

```
 add_filter( 'single_template', function( $template ) {

  $cpt = [ 'available-properties', 'leased-sold', 'norway' ];

  return in_array( get_queried_object()->post_type, $cpt, true )
    ? 'path/to/country-single.php'
    : $template;

} );
```

Comment: Can you please give me little more information, exactly what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Found the answer

This seems to work great!

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template )
 {
     // your custom post types
     $my_types = array( 'available-properties', 'leased-sold' );
     $post_type = get_post_type();

     if ( ! in_array( $post_type, $my_types ) )
         return $template;

     return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/page-content__projects-single.php';
 });
```